# How to dynamically recognize points via HTTPS ingestion?

Tags: elasticsearch, https, logstash

We are sending https requests to ingest data. How can the request be formatted so that Elastic dynamically maps the 'geo_point' field as type:point and not text or number? Thank you!

```
curl -X POST "https://in-https.URL" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "geo_point": -71.34, 41.12
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

geo_point dynamic mapping is not supported - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html.

To index a geo_point field, precede you original request with a request to _mapping to add your geo_point field to the index mapping - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html